# How can hide the textbox on basis on checkbox in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, checkbox

In my JSP page two fields one is textbox and one is checkbox, I tried with     j query and java script also for hiding the textbox on checked of checkbox but it is not reflecting. Below I am mentioning code here

```
<p class="contact"> <input id="check" name="check" value="check" style="margin-right: 10px" type="checkbox" tabindex="11">
        <label for="name"> Not Yet Registered</label> </p>


        <p class= "reg"><label for="reg">Register No.</label></p><br>
        <input id = "reg" maxlength="15"  name= "reg" placeholder="Reg No." type ="text" tabindex="12"><br><br>
```

J query

```
$('#check').click(function() {
  $('.reg')[this.checked ? "hide" : "show"]();
});
```

Kindly Help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`$('.reg')[this.checked ? "hide" : "show"]();`
```

this will hide only the `<p>` tag you need to use `$('#reg')[this.checked ? "hide" : "show"]();`
 
to hide the input box.

full code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').click(function () { 
        $('.reg')[this.checked ? "hide" : "show"]();                   
        $('#reg')[this.checked ? "hide" : "show"]();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use condition using if

```
if('#check').checked==true{
  $('#reg').css("display","none")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use change event

   ```
   $('#check').change(function() {
          $(this).is(":checked")?$('.reg').hide():$('.reg').show()
    });
   ```